# How to find specific longitude in 0 to 360 longitude range in R

Tags: r, subset, latitude-longitude, netcdf4

I have one netcdf file with all positive longitude ranges from 0 to 360. I need to subset Australia adjacent Pacific region ranges from 130E to 180. How to mention my longitude range in all positive longitude while sub setting in R.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It might help to read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248)

Answer (score 2):

After loading your lon dimension from the nc file, something like:

```
lon<-nc$dim$lon$vals
```

Now you have to find the range of where the respective latitude and longitude lie at.

You can use:

```
m<-which(lon==130)
n<-which(lon==180)
```

Now you just have to open the variable, for instance, T2M(Temperature at 2 meters) having dimensions [lon,lat,time]

```
T2M_Australia<-T2M[m:n,,]
```

Voila, you've just cropped your data.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to post reproducible data (see the comment), but in general, this is how I would do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(long_ranges = 1:360) %>%
 mutate(australia = if_else(long_ranges >= 130 & long_ranges <= 180,
                "australia",
                "not_australia")) %>%
filter(australia == "australia")
```